# Survival curve numeric or character value specifying x-axis scale

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am plotting a survival curve by `ggsurvplot()`, to transform days in years I use as argument `xscale="d_y"`. I have tried also `xscale=365.25` as suggested by the documentation.

The problem is that time axis is automatically labelled but not as I expected at year 1, 2, 3...

Instead I get 0.55, 1.1, and so on.
How can I label exactly at every round year?

Find the code below

```
install.packages('survMisc')
library("survminer")
time <- sample(200:500, 20, replace=T)
status <-sample(0:1, 20, replace=T)
group<-c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10))
df<-data.frame (time, status, group)
fit2 <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ group,data = df)
ggsurvplot(fit2, xscale="d_y")
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `scale_x_continuous`

Comment: It is not an option in `ggsurvplot()`

Comment: If `ggsurvplot()` is not base R, please specify the `package`.

Comment: If you think the answer is correct mark it as correct, do not delete the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data `time` doesn't go more than 1.34 years. But add `break.x.by=365` and you'll have he scale you want.

```
install.packages('survMisc')
library("survminer")
time <- sample(200:500, 20, replace=T)
status <-sample(0:1, 20, replace=T)
group<-c(rep("A", 10), rep("B", 10))
df<-data.frame (time, status, group)
fit2 <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ group,data = df)
ggsurvplot(fit2, xscale="d_y", break.x.by=365)
```